# three.js - json model is appearing too big on screen

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I'm doing three.js, I have used a JSON file to load it into THREE.js, my JSON file is the dog from clara.io. Everything works fine, problem is the 3D model is too big. Is there a way of decreasing its size of which its loaded onto the screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - loaders - JSON loader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #info {
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;
            }
            #info a, .button { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script src="three.js"></script>

        <script src="Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            var container, stats;
            var camera, scene, renderer;
            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;
            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
            init();
            animate();
            function init() {
                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
                camera.position.z = 4;
                // scene
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x444444 );
                scene.add( ambient );
                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
                directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ).normalize();
                scene.add( directionalLight );
                // BEGIN Clara.io JSON loader code
                var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
                objectLoader.load("blue-dog.json", function ( obj ) {
                    scene.add( obj );
                } );
                // END Clara.io JSON loader code
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
                //
                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
            }
            function onWindowResize() {
                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            }
            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
                mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
                mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;
            }
            //
            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();
            }
            function render() {
                camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
                camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;
                camera.lookAt( scene.position );
                renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

If anyone could be of any help please would appreciate it thank. I'm hosting it on WAMP as well. The JSON file is to big to paste in.

Comment: move your camera further away = model get smaller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either set the scale of your object:

```
objectLoader.load("blue-dog.json", function( obj ){
    obj.scale.set( .5, .5, .5 );
    scene.add( obj );
});
```

or zoom out your camera, but to be honest, I cannot give you the example because I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do regarding camera (that strange += -= in your render function confuses me a bit). You could try this:

```
camera.position.multiplyScalar( 2 ); 
// This should double the distance between your camera and the center of the scene
```

But only try it once (if you repeat this in your render loop, it will perpetually zoom out, and it would happen rather quickly).

Comment: sorry, how would I go abouts to set the scale

Comment: @shaneo Sorry I might have accidentally posted this prematurely. You set the scale of your mesh in `Mesh.scale.set( x, y, z )` (in your case your loaded `object` is a `Mesh`).

Comment: thank you, think that thing you mentioned in my render function is for animating the object with the mouse over. I used the example of three.js to see how to load a json model in. As i couldn't get it work. Is there also way of rotating the object as well. I want to rotate it 90 degrees

Comment: @shaneo You should have a read in the three.js documentation - rotating, scaling and moving meshes is stuff built into `Mesh`. Have a look here to see all the properties available on meshes: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=mesh#Reference/Objects/Mesh . I think you will have to try to read a bit more about this, as you need to get a feel for how things work in 3d, then the camera will make sense and so will the meshes.